Why does Renovate attempt to install packages?
In the logs of my Renovate job, there are lines
DEBUG: Executing command (branch="renovate/cdk")
{
  "command": "yarn install --ignore-engines --ignore-platform --network-timeout 100000 --ignore-scripts"
}

Why does Renovate need to install packages to do own work?
I'd imagine that Renovate needs to verify that there are no version conflicts in the proposed version upgrade by attemtping the installations. But if it knows how to install packages (in this case, it does yarn install), then it also knows how the packages specify their dependencies (in style "if it is yarn, then the dependencies are in package-lock.json"). If so, then it could just parse package-lock.json instead of attempting the installation, which is probably much faster.
Is this "imagination" correct?

Isn't it to update the package-lock.json file and/or run extra scripts configured in the build? Renovate won't download dependencies itself or lookup any files from the dependency if that's what you're suggesting.
